# Issue when trying to align text and textbox in one line inside the form?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
  <h1>Example Horizontal Form Bootstrap</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter your Email here........! Hello </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter your Email here........! Hello</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I want to place the "text and textbox" in one line. At present, I am getting text in multiple lines beside the textbox like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

Option 1:
Reduce the label text and/or increase the column allocated to it. Example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group form-row">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-row">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Option 2: You can use `text-truncate` class to truncate any overflow text. Example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group form-row">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right text-truncate">Enter your Email here........! Hello</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-row">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right text-truncate">Enter your Password here........! Hello</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```